# How to do annotations with Altair

Tags: python, text, annotate, altair

I am trying to write some text inside the figure to highlight something in my plot (equivalent to 'annotate' in matplotlib). Any idea? Thanks

Comment: See: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/349

Answer (score 9):

You can get annotations into your Altair plots in two steps:

1. Use `mark_text()` to specify the annotation's position, fontsize etc.
2. Use `transform_filter()` from `datum` to *select* the points (data subset) that needs the annotation. Note the line `from altair import datum.`

Code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

from altair import datum #Needed for subsetting (transforming data)


iris = data.iris()

points = alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength',
    y='petalWidth',
    color='species')

annotation = alt.Chart(iris).mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    fontSize = 20,
    dx = 7
).encode(
    x='petalLength',
    y='petalWidth',
    text='petalLength'
).transform_filter(
    (datum.petalLength >= 5.1) & (datum.petalWidth < 1.6)
)


points + annotation
```

which produces:
[image: Annotations in an Altair Plot]

These are static annotations. You can also get interactive annotations by binding `selections` to the plots.

Comment: How would you align all the text annotations at the bottom of the chart?

Comment: You can add `.transform_calculate(petalWidth="0.2")` at the end of the annotation graph to set the petalWidth to 0.2 and be at the bottom of the graph. Note that this must be given as a string