# How to annotate scatter points plotted with the prince library

Tags: python, pandas, altair, plot-annotations, correspondence-analysis

I am using the library `prince` in order to perform Correspondence Analysis

```
from prince import CA
```

My contingency table `dummy_contingency` looks like this:

```
{'v1': {'0': 4.479591836734694,
  '1': 75.08163265306122,
  '2': 1.1020408163265305,
  '3': 5.285714285714286,
  '4': 14.244897959183673,
  '5': 0.0,
  '6': 94.06122448979592,
  '7': 0.5102040816326531,
  '8': 87.62244897959184,
  '9': 16.102040816326532},
 'v2': {'0': 6.142857142857143,
  '1': 24.653061224489797,
  '2': 0.3979591836734694,
  '3': 2.63265306122449,
  '4': 18.714285714285715,
  '5': 0.0,
  '6': 60.92857142857143,
  '7': 1.030612244897959,
  '8': 71.73469387755102,
  '9': 14.76530612244898},
 'v3': {'0': 3.642857142857143,
  '1': 21.551020408163264,
  '2': 0.8061224489795918,
  '3': 2.979591836734694,
  '4': 14.5,
  '5': 0.030612244897959183,
  '6': 39.60204081632653,
  '7': 0.7551020408163265,
  '8': 71.89795918367346,
  '9': 11.571428571428571},
 'v4': {'0': 6.1020408163265305,
  '1': 25.632653061224488,
  '2': 0.6938775510204082,
  '3': 3.9285714285714284,
  '4': 21.581632653061224,
  '5': 0.22448979591836735,
  '6': 10.704081632653061,
  '7': 0.8469387755102041,
  '8': 71.21428571428571,
  '9': 12.489795918367347}}
```

Chi Square Test reveals dependence:

```
Chi-square statistic: 69.6630377155341
p-value: 1.2528156966101567e-05
```

Now I fit the data:

```
dummy_contingency = pd.DataFrame(dummy_contingency)

ca_dummy = CA(n_components=2)  # Number of components for correspondence analysis
ca_dummy.fit(dummy_contingency)
```

And the plot:

```
fig = ca_dummy.plot(
    X=dummy_contingency)
fig
```

[image: Actual Output]

How do I get the labelling done for this plot? The examples posted by others ([Using mca package in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521740/using-mca-package-in-python)) uses the function `plot_coordinates()` which has the option of putting the labels as well. But it looks like this function is no longer available with `prince` package and need to use the `plot()` function which does not have the option to put labels. Appreciate any help on this.

Edit:
Example of an output with labels:
[image: Expected Output]

The text for each of the points in the plot like "strawberries", "banana", "yogurt", etc. are the labels that I am looking for, which in this will be the index values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 for the blue points and the column names "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4" for the orange points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Adding the annotations to the scatter plot comes from [How to do annotations with Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50073666/7758804), however, this doesn't include the necessary steps to plot the points from `ca`.
- In order to annotate the `correspondence-analysis` plot, `.column_coordinates` and `.row_coordinates` must be extracted from the `ca` model. These are the points on the plot, not those from `df`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import prince
import altair as alt

# convert the dictionary of data to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_contingency)

# create the model
ca = prince.CA()

# fit the model
ca = ca.fit(df)

# extract the column coordinate dataframe, and change the column names
cc = ca.column_coordinates(df).reset_index()
cc.columns = ['name', 'x', 'y']

# extract the row coordinates dataframe, and change the column names
rc = ca.row_coordinates(df).reset_index()
rc.columns = ['name', 'x', 'y']

# combine the dataframes
crc_df = pd.concat([cc, rc], ignore_index=True)

# plot and annotate
points = ca.plot(df)

annot = alt.Chart(crc_df).mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    fontSize = 20,
    dx = 7
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    text='name'
)

points + annot
```

- Note the plot already has floating annotations, without adding `annot`.

[image]

---

- The annotations can also be added without combining `cc` and `rc` into a single dataframe.

```py
points = ca.plot(df)

annot1 = alt.Chart(cc).mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    fontSize = 20,
    dx = 7
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    text='name'
)

annot2 = alt.Chart(rc).mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    fontSize = 20,
    dx = 7
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    text='name'
)

points + annot1 + annot2
```

Comment: One word. Genius. Thank you.